# Help with spellathon puzzle

Tags: word

This is the spellathon puzzle:

[image: This is the spellathon puzzle.]

The words I've gotten so far are:
Mimic, mined, cloud, denim, angle, algae, angel, linen, eagle, and legal.

For some reason, I find this puzzle difficult to find words.

Just in case you don't know what spellathon is:

The idea of Spellathon is to form as many 5-letter words as you can by moving along the connecting lines from one letter to another. Do not skip letters. You may come back to a letter and use it more than once in the same word, but do not stand on a letter using it twice in direct succession. Words beginning with a capital letter, contractions, plurals, and hyphenated, obsolete, slang, poetic, archaic, foreign, and dialect words are not allowed. There are 27 words that the creator (Dell) found.

The puzzle was from Penny Dell Puzzles' Free Daily Puzzles section. https://www.pennydellpuzzles.com/puzzlers-corner/free-puzzles/

Comment: Could you edit the question to include more detail about where the puzzle comes from? If there's somewhere you can link to, include a link; if it comes from a book or something, say what; etc. We're very picky about proper attribution here, I'm afraid. Thanks!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I got it from the Penny Dell Puzzles' "Free Daily Puzzles" sections. It was a Dell puzzle.

Comment: Thanks! Er, are you _allowed_ to copy the puzzle here? Looking at their website, it seems like they don't mind people reproducing their puzzles for non-profitmaking purposes _on a small scale_ (school classrooms and the like), but even for that they want you to get a licensing agreement signed by someone from Dell. Something posted here is visible to _the whole world_.

Comment: Their "free puzzles" aren't really free, in that you have to give them your email address and agree to get promotional emails from them. (So they're obviously hoping that at some point you'll buy things.) The rest of us haven't given Dell our email addresses and permission to try to sell us things, so in some sense they really are missing out on something by having their puzzle reproduced here.

Comment: Well, oops.                                           heh heh

Comment: I'm afraid we'd better close it for that reason. Sorry!

Comment: I'm closing this as off-topic because it's a copyrighted thing from a source that hasn't given permission to reproduce it. (Of course it isn't really _off-topic_. We have a limited range of reasons we can use here and this is one of the cases where none of them quite fits.)

Comment: Ok. I guess that's fine with me.

Comment: This must have been an annoying first experience on PSE. I hope you'll stay around despite it :-).

Comment: I definitely will. I love puzzles.

Comment: @Northex please have a look at the updated answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is not my first language, so this <s>is</s> was hard for me.

Starting:

> Cline, cling, lingo, glean, lined, aloud

A word-list with [350.000](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/) words is reduced to these 114 words. Some of them are names of species, for instance [aegla](https://www.google.com/search?q=aegla&oq=aegla&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l6j69i60.1055j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and there might be some impossible letter-combinations I've missed.

> aegle, agena, agene, aging, agnel, agoge, alala, alane, alang, alani, aldea, alden, aldol, algae, algal, algic, algin, algol, align, aline, aloud, anana, anele, angel, angle, anglo, animi, cinel, clang, cline, cling, cloud, deled, denim, dodge, dogal, dolci, dougl, dugal, eagle, edged, elean, enage, engin, engle, gaged, galea, galen, galga, ganga, gange, genae, genal, genic, genin, gilim, glaga, glali, glean, glede, glene, goala, golgi, gouge, gudge, gugal, icing, imine, inane, ingan, ingle, inigo, lagan, lagen, lagna, lanao, langi, lango, leden, ledge, ledol, legal, legoa, lenin, ligan, ligne, linea, lined, linen, linga, linge, lingo, linin, loden, lodge, logan, logic, login, milan, mimic, minae, mined, minge, mingo, minim, mnage, nagel, naled, nanga, nigel, ogled, ogmic, ugali

I can reduce this to 22 words that I **know** I've either said or written myself:

> aging, algae, align, aloud, angel, angle, cling, cloud, denim, dodge, edged, icing, inane, ledge, legal, lined, linen, lingo, lodge, logic, mimic, mined

There are other words in that list I know the meaning of too. I haven't googled all the words, so there might be some that are names, such as [Nanga](https://www.google.com/search?q=nanga&oq=nanga&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.1605j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Yeah... I don't have a wide vocabulary, but word puzzles, they sort of _need_ rare words, or the puzzle doesn't work.